# Crashlytics custom key not appearing in crash

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to figure out how to link each and every crash with application user id. I got to know we can achieve this functionality with [firebase customized key logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android).

For POC purpose, I have added custom key after logged in completion and then I am crashing app on next screen. But Custom keys are not getting logged on console.

Here, how I am adding custom key :

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey("userId", serverLoginResponse.getBody().getUserId());
```

And I am crashing application on next screen using `divide by 0`.

```
int i = 2;
int j = i / 0;
```

But keys are not gettging tagged to crash. Please see screenshots.

**On Dashboard.**
[image]

**on Crash Details Screen :**

[image]

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable the collection in your activity but preferable in the Main Application Class

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

Follow this guide:

[FirebaseCrashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/crashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that key/values set using `setCustomValue(_,_)` didn't persist between app relaunches. I had to call the setCustomValue code everytime on app relaunch aka `appDidFinishingWithOptions(_)`. See related solution and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68097562/4970749

Note that setCustomValue here affects Crashlytics dashboard which is the second screenshot you showed here, under "Crash Details Screen." It doesn't update Firebase Analytics keys/properties (first screenshot), thats a separate method (try: `Analytics.setUserProperty(value, forName: name)` for that first screenshot).